# 1990s Overhead view game involving post-apocalyptic gangs, including yuppies who propel grenades with tennis racquets

Tags: story-identification, video-games

I'm pretty sure this was in the 1990s. I saw a review for it in *[VideoGames and  Computer Entertainment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VideoGames_%26_Computer_Entertainment)* and later acquired a copy of it (probably through illicit means given my habits back then). It was over-head viewpoint, maybe with 2-D graphics for the fixed viewpoint. You were fighting various gangs, I'm pretty sure in a post-apocalyptic landscape. The one enemy that's stuck with me through the years is yuppies in tennis outfits who use their racquets to hurl grenades at the player. Other than that, I think it was the usual mixture of melee weapons and guns. It was one of those games where dozens of enemies attack at a time. I think they contrasted it to games like *Unreal* which had much more intelligent enemies, but could only have one or two active due to system limitations. The other thing I remember is that there were different areas you could complete, with a "hub world" from which you could access the other areas. I want to say the review specifically called out the "hub world" concept.

It was on a PC, probably Windows 3.11 or Windows 95, although it's possible it ran in MS-DOS. The last thing that I recall is that I think the title was three words, something like "Kill Them All" (although a search for that just gets me a modern zombie shooter).

Comment: Was it definitely Unreal it was being compared to?  Unreal didn't come out until 1998, while the internet says that magazine folded in 1996.  Narrowing the date range down would help with identification.

Comment: @ssav: Hmm... that would cast doubt on my memory. I don't know for certain. I remember reading about Unreal and a commentary on its scarce but smart enemies versus the approach of more plentiful but primitive foes, and I remember this game being commented on having tons of attackers at once, but I might be conflating two different articles.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're probably thinking of [Take No Prisoners](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Take_No_Prisoners_(video_game)).

> The game is set in San Antonio, Texas, in a post-apocalyptic near-future. The player takes the role of Slade, a mercenary soldier recruited by Martech Industries, Inc. to retrieve a crystal located in the Dome, in the center of the desolated city, which protects those within from the harmful radiation consuming the planet. He must make his way through a chaotic San Antonio and fight military, civilian and security forces combined with irradiated mutants to reach the Dome and retrieve the crystal. This is intended to create a new Dome, and how it is used results in one of two different endings. The end of the game also suggests a sequel, but it was never released.

It was a great game, with a fairly unique (at the time) open-world format which sadly doesn't run well on newer systems. The game world was divided up into different territories controlled by various gangs/cults, including zombies, mutants, robots, and yes, yuppies with tennis grenades.

This [Let's Play](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2DYbAeEM4Ug) shows the Yuppies. They are also mentioned in this [walkthrough](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/pc/198884-take-no-prisoners/faqs/52498); they appear in the Bryce transit terminal area.